# What is the difference between alternatives().conditional() and any().when()?

Tags: node.js, schema, joi

Straight from the docs, `alternatives.conditional`:

> Adds a conditional alternative schema type, either based on another key value, or a schema peeking into the current value

`any.when`:

> Adds conditions that are evaluated during validation and modify the schema before it is applied to the value

How are they different? Specifically, when will the result of one differ from the result of the other?

---

I found in `alternatives.conditional` docs a note about `any.when`:

> Note that `alternatives.conditional()` is different than `any.when()`. When you use `any.when()` you end up with composite schema of all the matching conditions while `alternatives.conditional()` will use the first matching schema, ignoring other conditional statements.

But I don't understand, what does it mean?

---

References:

- [Joi docs: alternatives().conditional()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.1#alternativesconditionalcondition-options)
- [Joi docs: any().when()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.1#anywhencondition-options)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this phrase:

> `alternatives.conditional()` will use the first matching schema, ignoring other conditional statements.

If you have multiple `conditionals()` only the first matching one affects the schema of the key.

```js
Joi.object({
  a: Joi.alternatives()
    .conditional("c", { is: Joi.number().min(10), then: Joi.forbidden() })
    .conditional("b", {
      is: Joi.exist(),
      then: Joi.valid("y"),
      otherwise: Joi.valid("z"),
    }),
  b: Joi.any(),
  c: Joi.number(),
});
```

For the above schema, if the object does not have key `c` less than 10, only then the second conditional comes into effect.
Meaning

`{ a : 'z' , c : 11 , b : 2 }` will say , "a" is not allowed (first condition).
But `{ a : 'z' , c : 7 , b : 2 }` will say , "a" must be [y] (second condition).

If you tweak the above condition to do something like this (I have only added an `otherwise` clause):

```js
Joi.object({
  a: Joi.alternatives()
    .conditional("c", {
      is: Joi.number().min(10),
      then: Joi.forbidden(),
      otherwise: Joi.valid("x"),
    })
    .conditional("b", {
      is: Joi.exist(),
      then: Joi.valid("y"),
      otherwise: Joi.valid("z"),
    }),
  b: Joi.any(),
  c: Joi.number(),
});
```

then you have an invalid schema with the error: `Unreachable condition`. Because here the first condition will definitely result in something (It has both `then` and `otherwise`).

But according to this:

> When you use `any.when()` you end up with composite schema of all the matching conditions

With `any.when()` the whole chain is read until end, to decide the final schema.

```js
const schema = {
  a: Joi.any()
    .valid("x")
    .when("b", {
      is: Joi.exist(),
      then: Joi.valid("y"),
      otherwise: Joi.valid("z"),
    })
    .when("c", { is: Joi.number().min(10), then: Joi.forbidden() }),
  b: Joi.any(),
  c: Joi.number(),
};
```

when `b` exists, then `y` is a valid value for `a`, but when `c` is a number greater than equal to `10` then `a` is not allowed.

For example below is a valid object for above schema:

```js
{
  a: 'y', //'x' also works
  b: 20,
  c: 9
}
```

but this is not:

```js
{
  a: 'y',
  b: 20,
  c: 10
}
```

Also, alternatives add an extra alternative to try and do not affect the original type.

Look at the below schema:

```js
Joi.object({
  a: Joi.alternatives(["x"]).conditional("b", {
    is: true,
    then: Joi.forbidden(),
  }),
  b: Joi.boolean(),
});
```

`{ b: true, a: 'x' }` will pass it. `Joi.forbidden()` cannot affect the fact that `x` is on of the valid values. If you pass `{ b: true , a: 'y' }`, this will definitely fail and you will see `"a" is not allowed`.

If you write the above rule with `when`:

```js
Joi.object({
  a: Joi.valid("x").when("b", { is: true, then: Joi.forbidden() }),
  b: Joi.boolean(),
});
```

then, `{ b : true, a: 'x' }` will fail as expected because `when` can affect the overall type of the key.

Comment: Ok, so they're mainly different when you chain their return values (`conditional().conditional()` vs `when().when()`). Are they at all different if composite? (`conditional(conditional()) vs when(when())`)?

Comment: I mean the second part of the answer also plays a role. `alternatives.conditional()` can not affect the key, it can only give more alternatives whereas `while` can alter the whole keys schema.

Comment: Do have a look at this : https://joi.dev/tester/ to play around

Comment: When will `{ a: Joi.boolean(), b: Joi.boolean(), c: Joi.alternatives().conditional("a", { is: true, then: Joi.any(), otherwise: Joi.alternatives().conditional("b", { is: true, then: Joi.any(), otherwise: Joi.string().required() }) }) }` behave different from `{ a: Joi.boolean(), b: Joi.boolean(), c: Joi.any().when("a", { is: true, then: Joi.any(), otherwise: Joi.any().when("b", { is: true, then: Joi.any(), otherwise: Joi.string().required() }) }) }`?

Comment: lets narrow it down, why does order matter for `alternatives.conditional` but not for `any.when`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74004911/why-does-order-matter-for-alternatives-conditional-but-not-for-any-when